# Python -Rest API and List Comprehension

Tags: python, rest

I wondered if someone could cast their eyes over this code I am trying to write and having some issues, I have probably made a mistake somewhere but cannot seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

this data is from a rest api query, therefore I want to extract information from it if possible.

```
data = {'l3extOut': {'attributes': {'annotation': '', 'dn': 'uni/tn-N4-CUST-TEST/out-L3OUT'}}, 
'l3extOut': {'attributes': {'uid': '500', 'dn': 'uni/tn-N4-CUST-TEST_DEV/out-L3OUT'}}, 
'l3extLNodeP': {'attributes': {'annotation': '', 'dn': 'uni/tn-N4-CUST-TEST/out-L3OUT/lnodep-NODES', 'name': 'NODES'}},
'l3extRsNodeL3OutAtt': {'attributes': {'annotation': '', 'dn': 'uni/tn-N4-CUST-TEST/out-L3OUT/lnodep-NODES/rsnodeL3OutAtt-[topology/pod-1/node-101]', 'rType': 'mo', 'rtrId': '1.1.1.101', 'rtrIdLoopBack': 'yes'}}}
```

```
print(type(data))
```

This is a dict when ran in the terminal.

what I am trying to achieve is that I need to be able to access information from the headers below.

```
l3extOut
l3extLNodeP
l3extRsNodeL3OutAtt
```

For example, within the list `l3extOut`, I need the DN value and UID
for example within the list `l3extLNodeP`, I need the name
for example within the list `l3extRsNodeL3OutAtt`, I need the DN value

I tried using the below thinking I could just extract the information that I wanted and this works if the headers are the same value but they are not in this case. Is there a better way of achieving what I need

```
data_list = []
for x in data:
    dn = x['l3extOut']['attributes']['dn']
    uid = x['l3extOut']['attributes']['uid']
    node = x ['l3extLNodeP']['attributes']['name']
    path = x ['l3extRsNodeL3OutAtt']['attributes']['dn']
    output = f'{dn} {uid} {node} {path}'
    data_list.append(f'{dn} {uid} {node} {path} ')

print(data_list)
```

**dn = x['l3extOut']['attributes']['dn']  TypeError: string indices must be integers**

Comment: Based on the data you passed, there is only a single `data['l3extOut']['attributes']['don']`.

Comment: In addition to what @FrankYellin said, iterating over a dict will return the keys, so you an repro your exception by doing `"foo"["bar"]`.  Try doing `print([path for path in data])` and seeing what you get.

Answer (score 0):

For your method 1, make the below change in your list comprehension:

```
dn = [data[path]['attributes']['dn'] for path in data]
print(dn)

# result shows
# ['uni/tn-common/out-default']
```

For your method 2, make the below change in your for loop:

```
data_list = []
for x in data:
    dn_new = data[x]['attributes']['dn']
    uid = data[x]['attributes']['uid']
    output = f'{dn_new} {uid}'
    data_list.append(f'{dn_new} {uid} ')

print(data_list)

# result shows
# ['uni/tn-common/out-default 0 ']
```

Actually `for path in data:` and `for x in data:`, both will return the dictionary key `'l3extOut'`.

Comment: okay thank you, I will give that a try. Just so I am clear, if there was more keys in the data variable, I should be able to use the same code. for example in the data variable, there could be another key, like this - {'l3extRsEctx': {'attributes': {'dn': 'uni/tn-common/out-default/rsectx','tDn': 'uni/tn-common/ctx-default', 'uid': '2'}}}. again I would need to ['l3extRsEctx']['attributes']['dn'].

Comment: @Hooch_dgb, Seems like you haven't properly edited `data` in question. However both of the methods in my answer will work properly for nested `data` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The top level key in your *data* dictionary seems to be irrelevant. Therefore:

```
data = {'l3extOut': {'attributes': {'annotation': '', 'childAction': '', 'descr': '', 'dn': 'uni/tn-common/out-default', 'enforceRtctrl': 'export', 'extMngdBy': '', 'lcOwn': 'local', 'modTs': '2022-03-24T22:13:00.281+01:00', 'monPolDn': 'uni/tn-common/monepg-default', 'mplsEnabled': 'no', 'name': 'default', 'nameAlias': '', 'ownerKey': '', 'ownerTag': '', 'status': '', 'targetDscp': 'unspecified', 'uid': '0', 'userdom': 'all'}}}

for v in data.values():
    print(v['attributes']['dn'])
```

This allows for multiple keys at the same level as 'l3extOut' but assumes that the associated values have the same structure as shown in the sample data **and** that the 'attributes' and 'dn' keys exist within those values

Comment: yeah thats because the data is incomplete, il change the post now

Comment: You may want to review the edit in your question

Comment: @Hooch_dgb The *data* edit makes no sense

Comment: thats what the API gives me. its a dict. with multiple keys. I am trying to extract information from it, so for l3extOut. I want the DN values and for l3extRsEctx I want to UID values

Comment: @Hooch_dgb Your edit is broken. Try this answer against the API response and I'm confident that it will work

Comment: yeah I did try your solution, however I got the following error > print(v['attributes']['dn'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Comment: @Hooch_dgb In that case the data you're working with doesn't match what's shown in the question